# WPF - Catch Errors from unmanaged Legacy C++ Code

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf

I am on a team building a WPF application for the UI, while reusing much of the core application (graphics processing and 3d modeling) which was originally developed in C++ / OpenGL. The issue I am facing is I cannot seem to catch exceptions thrown from the C++ layer. I have a global error handling for the WPF application which does catch all the unhanded C# exceptions. I need to do something similar to catch the C++ exceptions but so far I haven't been able to get it to work. The code is below.

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        /// <summary>
        /// Overrides Application.OnStartup to register the global exception handler
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException +=
                new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Application_DispatcherUnhandledException);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomain_UnhandledException;
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }

        private void AppDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Application encountered an unhandled exception", e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
            GenericDialog genericDialog = new GenericDialog(OmegaConstant.DialogType.Error, 
                String.Format("Application has encountered an unhandled exception leaving the application in an unstable state. Error: {0}", 
                e.ToString()), 900);
            genericDialog.ShowDialog();
            Logger.Error("Application is shutting down");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Hanndles all uncaught exceptions from C# layer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender,
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Application encountered an unhandled exception", e.Exception);
            GenericDialog genericDialog = new GenericDialog(OmegaConstant.DialogType.Error, 
                String.Format("Application has encountered an unhandled exception leaving the application in an unstable state. Error: {0}", 
                e.Exception.Message), e.Exception, true, 900);
            genericDialog.ShowDialog();
            e.Handled = true;
            Logger.Error("Application is shutting down");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to handle access violation errors? They disabled such errors propagation in .net 4 since application may be in unpredictable state. [legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) config attribute may help if you really want to catch these errors.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. I don't want to handle them per se, but the requirement is to log them and close the application gracefully if possible. I don't intend to try to continue executing since the state of the app cannot be guaranteed.